# Yii 2.0: Access model data from a view

Tags: php, model-view-controller, yii, view, yii2

Please suggest which is the best practice to access the models from a view templates in Yii 2.0.

Let's say I have a view template file `index.php` which includes other template named `_form.php`, which includes file `_params.php` etc. And I need to access some model's methods.

So I have create those models and transfer them from view to view using construction `$this->render('_template', ['model' => $model, 'model2' => $model2, ...])`?
Or better I need to use widgets?
Or include model into a view and access directly breaking the rules of MVC pattern?

For example, I need to use only one method from a model to create a dropdown menu. I should transfer whole model? Or better I should prepare dropdown array in model or controller and transfer that array instead?

Comment: Since Yii provides many different ways you can say that there is no general rule, but that depends on the type of result you want to achieve .. if you have to be a collection of items you can use the dataProvider and widgets that manage collections (like grdiview ) if you need individual models you can use one or more models and one or more widget ..but for a more accurate answer you should formulate an example more precise and detailed

Answer (score 0):

**Try this one**

*For example file*

**Model file**

> $product_details = ArrayHelper::map(Products::find()->all(), 'pid',
>
> product_name');
>
> return $this->render('new_purchase', ['model' =>
>
> $model,'product_details'=>$product_details]);

**View file**

```
  <select name="product_id[]" class="form-control">

    <?php foreach($product_details as $key=>$val)

    { 


    ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $key; ?>"><?php echo $val; ?></option>

    <?php } ?>

    </select>
```